# Different renders of different objects with the same materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, scene

I need to make some renders of different objects with the same materials. Each object needs to be rendered alone from different angles and they need to look alike because they are built from the same materials. Also, the lightning should be the same (I'm using environment lighting because the objects contain some glossy parts).

I was wondering what is the most efficient way to accomplish this; if I should put them all in different layers in the same blend file with linked materials and switch manually the layer each time to be rendered, or if I should split them across multiple blend files and somehow link the material + environment light, or if I should use different scenes (I don't know how this works), etc.

I'm using Cycles.

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Depending on how many objects you have, I would put each object on its own layer in the same blend file. Keep them all at (0,0,0,) and just turn off/on which one you want to render. If you have more objects than layers I would put them all at (0,0,0) and turn off the camera icon in the outliner so it doesn't render.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Is there any way to batch render all the layers?

Comment: Yes I believe there is a way but you would have to find a Python script to take care of that for you. I am a novice at Python so I don't think I would be of much help. Im sure some of the coders in the forum could help you out.